Response 403 forbidden at simultaneously ajax request using Jakarta EE and Glassfish Server
I have a Jakarta-based web app deployed in Glassfish 7.0.16. Currently, I'm implementing Jakarta Security with user-role from DB. That works fine until the client-side execute multiple ajax requests at the same time, it starts responding 403 forbidden beginning from 2° or 3° ajax request. Actually, it occurs sometimes around 3 of 10 times.
I've tried to change security settings as <security-role> in web.xml, @ServletSecurity in Servlet file, and @inject SecurityContext into Servlet class
I removed @ServletSecurity in my Servlet class and wrote a filter, where I inject SecurityContext and checks as follow:
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

 @Inject
 SecurityContext sc;

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {

  HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
  HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

  if (req.isUserInRole("ROLE_A") || sc.isCallerInRole("ROLE_A")) {
   doChain(request, response);
  } else {
   // log info about Principal and session attributes
  }
 }
}

Like I mentioned above, if the client-side make 6 simultaneously ajax requests, one of them will respond 403 forbidden. Checking the generated log within else fragment, all session attributes and Principal are there like the another 5 ajax requests.
Some idea of what it is happening?

Sounds like request throttling. Are you sure it's Glassfish and not some kind of proxy like NGINX in front of it?

@Gimby thanks for the quick reply. I tested the web app on my dev laptop and production server, and the issue was triggered in both. I don't have a custom proxy in my dev laptop, only default Windows settings. I moved Ajax requests to web services and applied a manual check role in a filter. The first check is with isUserInRole(). If it fails, the second checker takes over: myObject.getRoles().contains("ROLE_A")

It looks like this is a known issue in GlassFish reported also here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/25141

This looks like the known issue already reported for GlassFish. I think I found a fix for it, with this change: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/25141.
Watch for the new GlassFish version which should bring the fix.
